# How to use the SQL MINUS keyword

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I am building a social network using asp.net sql, but I am having a problem with using MINUS Operator on SQL. I Select all friend's user data using following keywords

```
Select * from [UserData]
```

And i want to reduce following query from that query

```
SELECT *
FROM   [Friendship]
WHERE  Friend2 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'
       AND Friend_Status = 1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   [Friendship]
WHERE  Friend1 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'
       AND Friend_Status = 1
```

I tried to it , but when i run this , it gives me details for still this query

```
Select * from [UserData]
```

This is the code i tried

```
SELECT *
FROM   [UserData]
MINUS
SELECT *
FROM   [Friendship]
WHERE  Friend2 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'
       AND Friend_Status = 1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   [Friendship]
WHERE  Friend1 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'
       AND Friend_Status = 1
```

Could you tell me guys how to use this MINUS OPERATOR as i wish?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `EXCEPT` functionality. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Sql Server` you can use [**`Except`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator which is the equivalent of `Minus`

> EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t
>   output by the right input query.

Query should be like

```
SELECT *
FROM   [UserData]
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT *
       FROM   [Friendship]
       WHERE  Friend2 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'
              AND Friend_Status = 1
       UNION
       SELECT *
       FROM   [Friendship]
       WHERE  Friend1 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'
              AND Friend_Status = 1) a
```

**Note :** Make sure you have equal no. of column in `Freindship` and `UserData` table

Comment: thanks but it gives me that error An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: @SoftwaresAŋɖTricks This error is not because of `Sql` code. Might from the Application

Comment: can i use NOT IN without using EXCEPT

Comment: @SoftwaresAŋɖTricks Yes, But you need to have a common column bewteen those two tables

Comment: why did u add another Select * FROM  status??

Comment: @SoftwaresAŋɖTricks Else `except` is going to happen between `first and second query`. But what you need is the result(union) of the second and third query not be present in first query.

Comment: is that printing mistake? you add a  "a" letter to the last of the query

Comment: @SoftwaresAŋɖTricks It is needed `sub select` requires an `alias name`

Answer (score 1):

Minus is Oracle syntax.
SQL server equivalent of MINUS is EXCEPT

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic289916-23-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also good mention that your third code sample runs without errors because `MINUS` is nothing but a table alias there. In fact it says:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [UserData] AS MINUS;

SELECT *
FROM   [Friendship]
...
```

`MINUS` is not a language keyword, so for the query compiler it's simply a random string that qualifies as an alias.

If you don't realize this, it can be very confusing to see two queries "connected" by a `MINUS` simply output two result sets.